# Deep linking flutter app when user clicks google maps link disambiguation dialog not showing

Tags: flutter, dart, dialog, disambiguation, flutter-deep-link

In my flutter rider app when user click on google map link outside of my flutter rider app when my app not active.Then disambiguation dialog is not appearing to select my app.I just wanted to list my app in the disambiguation dialog when user clicks on google map link. I just tried to implement deep linking and dynamic linking but the disambiguation dialog is not showing.

I just tried to implement deep linking and dynamic linking but the disambiguation dialog is not showing.I just wanted to list my flutter app in the disambiguation dialog when user clicks on google map link even when the is not active

Comment: share code snippet what you have tried so far